# How to install wireless driver in Fedora 15?

Tags: fedora, compiling, wifi

I have tried ndiswrapper 1.56 for fc15... it gives the following error  :

```
$ make  
make -C driver  
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/dhinesh/sware/ndiswrapper-1.56/driver'  
make -C /usr/src/kernels/2.6.38.6-26.rc1.fc15.i686.PAE M=/home/dhinesh/sware/ndiswrapper-1.56/driver  
make[2]: Entering directory `/usr/src/kernels/2.6.38.6-26.rc1.fc15.i686.PAE'  
 CC [M]  /home/dhinesh/sware/ndiswrapper-1.56/driver/loader.o  
/home/dhinesh/sware/ndiswrapper-1.56/driver/loader.c:834:2: error: unknown field ‘ioctl’ specified in initializer  
/home/dhinesh/sware/ndiswrapper-1.56/driver/loader.c:834:2: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]  
/home/dhinesh/sware/ndiswrapper-1.56/driver/loader.c:834:2: warning: (near initialization for ‘wrapper_fops.llseek’) [enabled by default]  
make[3]: ** [/home/dhinesh/sware/ndiswrapper-1.56/driver/loader.o] Error 1 
make[2]: ** [_module_/home/dhinesh/sware/ndiswrapper-1.56/driver] Error 2  
make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/kernels/2.6.38.6-26.rc1.fc15.i686.PAE'  
make[1]: ** [modules] Error 2  
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/dhinesh/sware/ndiswrapper-1.56/driver'  
make: ***[all] Error 2
```

How can I get out of this? Or any other distro to install wireless driver?

Answer (score 3):

Do you have a compelling reason to build them on your own? If not, I suggest you to take two steps:

- Install the rpmfusion repository

Perform this on the command line:

```
su -c 'yum localinstall --nogpgcheck http://download1.rpmfusion.org/free/fedora/rpmfusion-free-release-stable.noarch.rpm http://download1.rpmfusion.org/nonfree/fedora/rpmfusion-nonfree-release-stable.noarch.rpm'
```

- Install the akmod-ndiswrapper from the rpmfusion repository

Once again, on the command line:

```
su -c 'yum install akmod-ndiswrapper'
```

Answer (score 0):

I will say to prefer the driver built for linux than using the Windows driver through ndiswrapper. For proper installation guide, refer [wireless kernel site](http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers)  and find the device driver which your system supports and install it using the instructions given.